# Jmeter display hardcoded variable

Tags: http, variables, request, jmeter

I am trying to display `${__P{timestamp_start,1451404741})` and using it as [image]

but when I run and use it in http sampler as parameter to send with the request like this: [image]

I find out that the request was sent as following: [image]

I dont know why can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 2):

Should be `${__P(propname)}`

as opposed to `${__P{propname}}`

Please pay attention to the inner braces.